# Replace values in one matrix with NAs from another at same positions

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices of the same shape both filled with floats, but one of the matrices has NAs in some positions. I want to make it so the other matrix also has NAs at the same positions.

I can think of some naive solutions:

1) Any sort of conditional looping - very slow

2) Convert NAs to 0s, multiply the matrices elementwise so that the matrix without NAs gets 0s in desired positions, and then divide them elementwise to revert to original values and finally convert 0s to NAs - faster, but still inefficient and clunky

I want to find an efficient way of solving this problem since I need to perform this operation some millions of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A` is the matrix with `NaN` values and `B` is the other matrix.

```
import numpy as np

# Construct example matrices
A = np.random.random((3,3))
B = np.random.random((3,3))
# Set two values to np.nan
A[0,:2] = np.nan
# Set values in B to np.nan in the same locations that they occur in A
B[np.isnan(A)] = np.nan
```